# shell command to truncate/cut a part of string

Tags: shell, awk, grep, cut

I have a file with the below contents. I got the command to print version number out of it. But I need to truncate the last part in the version file

file.spec:

```
Version: 3.12.0.2
```

Command used:

```
VERSION=($(grep -r "Version:" /path/file.spec | awk  '{print ($2)}'))

echo $VERSION
```

Current output : 3.12.0.2

**Desired output : 3.12.0**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
VERSION=($(grep -r "Version:" /path/file.spec| awk  '{print ($2)}' | cut -d. -f1-3))
```

Cut split string with field delimiter (-d) , then you select desired field with -f param.

Comment: You can omit the `1` in the cut command and the parentheses in the `awk` statement which makes it even shorter: `VERSION=($(grep -r "Version:" /path/file.spec| awk  '{print $2}' | cut -d. -f-3))`

Answer (score 9):

There is absolutey no need for external tools like `awk`, `sed` etc. for this simple task if your shell is POSIX-compliant (which it should be) and supports [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02):

```
$ cat file.spec
Version: 3.12.0.2
$ version=$(<file.spec)
$ version="${version#* }"
$ version="${version%.*}"
$ echo "${version}"
3.12.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this single `awk` script `awk -F'[ .]' '{print $2"."$3"."$4}'`:

```
$ VERSION=$(awk -F'[ .]' '{print $2"."$3"."$4}' /path/file.spec)

$ echo $VERSION
3.12.0
```

---

Or this single `grep`

```
$ VERSION=$(grep -Po 'Version: \K\d+[.]\d+[.]\d' /path/file.spec)

$ echo $VERSION
3.12.0
```

But you never need `grep` and `awk` together.

Answer (score 1):

if you only grep single file, `-r` makes no sense.

also based on the output of your command line, this grep should work:

```
grep -Po '(?<=Version: )(\d+\.){2}\d+' /path/file.spec
```

gives you:

```
3.12.0
```

the `\K` is also nice. worked for fixed/non-fixed length look-behind. (since PCRE 7.2). There is another answer about it. but I feel look-behind is easier to read, if fixed length.